# Java GUI Layout Issues

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a simple program in Java that requires 8 `JLabels` on the top with one `JButton` directly below it. I tried using `BoxLayout` and then `FlowLayout`, but what happens is the `JLabels` disappear at the start of the program. When the `button` is clicked, everything is displayed properly, but you have to manually resize the window. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
public class ProgramUI {
   private JButton _jbutton; 
   private ArrayList<JLabel> _jlabels;
   private JFrame _jframe; 
   private JPanel _top, _bottom; 

public ProgramUI(){
_jframe = new JFrame (); 
_jframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(_jframe.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

_top = new JPanel();
_jframe.add(_top);

_bottom = new JPanel();
_jframe.add(_bottom);

_top.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
_bottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

_jlabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    _jlabels.add(label); 
    _top.add(label);
    //...rest of code is not relevant
 }

 _jbutton = new JButton();  
    _bottom.add(_jbutton);

_jframe.pack();
_jframe.setVisible(true);
_jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend neither `FlowLayout` nor `BoxLayout`. `BoxLayout`
is very simplistic and non-portable. `FlowLayout` is not even a layout
manager, it's a joke.

I recommend to use either built-in `GroupLayout` or third-party `MigLayout`. You need to dedicate some time for learning how to
create a good layout.

Here is your example with `MigLayout`.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class ProgramUI extends JFrame {

    public ProgramUI() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("nogrid"));

        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"));
        add(new JLabel("Label"), "wrap");
        add(new JButton("Button"));

        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            ProgramUI ex = new ProgramUI();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Exampe screenshot]